# Where does the Kendo UI Autocomplete cache its data?

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a project where I have the Kendo UI Autocomplete installed and working nicely. I have turned off server-side filtering and turned on caching with the control. I have verified that the method specified (I'm using it in and MVC 4 environment) in the controller is called only once and that the filtering is happening on the client side.

Before I deploy my application, I need to know for sure that the control caches all of its data on the client, and not in the application pool or anything like that.

Comment: No, it's all in memory on the client. All the MVC wrappers do is generate the HTML and JavaScript necessary to work.

Answer (score 1):

The data for the AutoComplete will be read once into a new Kendo `DataSource` instance, and assigned [dataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#configuration-dataSource) property of the AutoComplete widget. The widget then won't need to query the server for data again because the data is retained in an array in that DataSource.

You can verify this by looking at the data that is in the DataSource, if you get a reference to the AutoComplete widget.

```
var data = $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").dataSource.data();
```